# Scroll div when no other div is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have set up [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3Ej8/) to show what I want to achieve.

I have two `div`s (there can be more then two, but this is simple setup) with size of the parent window, so `<body>` will never scroll.

I want to bind an event listener to `window.scroll` so that if no other `div` is scrolled (nothing is scrolled) then `.mainContent` is scrolled.

For example if I'm scrolling on `.sidebar`, just scroll sidebar. But if my cursor is at the right edge and I scroll with the mouse wheel, then `.mainContent` should scroll, as if the body had overflow.

Do I explain it well?

My Question is how to detect if no other element is scrolled when I rotate my mouse wheel so I can scroll `.mainContent` in that case.

Comment: Do you want both divs to scroll on mousewheel?

Comment: Okay tell me If I got this right, You only want the div on which your cursor is, to scroll not any other, right ?

Comment: no, only one. and sometimes sidebar will not be scrollable, and sometimes it will. when sidebar is scrollable, scroll sidebar, but when it is not and I scroll sidebar, just scroll .mainContent.

Comment: I want to detect if element I had cursor at did scroll, if not scroll .mainContent

Comment: @Mpa4Hu i will try to make a fiddle frm what i have understood.check for an answer later

Comment: Answer was deleted so I'll extend my question here ) (I still hope @Zword got my question right )

You see, when I scroll body, I want to .mainCOntent to be scrolled, but If I scroll sidebar, just scroll sidebar.

For example, take this page, I can scroll anywhere and page will scroll. I moved overflow to .maincContent but I want to preserve this functionallity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz989/)**.Works in most browsers:

```
//Swap values of the below two variables if needed
var scrollDiv1=$('.mainContent'),
    scrollDiv2=$('.sidebar');

var s=0;
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
$(window).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
    if(s==0)
    {
    var evt = window.event || e;
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;             
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;
    if(delta > 0) {
        scrollDiv1.stop()
        .animate({scrollTop :scrollDiv1.scrollTop()-100},'linear');
    }
    else{
        scrollDiv1.stop()
        .animate({scrollTop :scrollDiv1.scrollTop()+100},'linear');
    }
    }
    s=0;
});

scrollDiv2.bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
    s=1;
});
```

---

To include `wheel` change variable( *mousewheelevt* ) value to :

```
var mousewheelevt = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : // Modern browsers
          document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : // Webkit + IE
          "DOMMouseScroll"; // Remaining (Previous firefox versions)
```

Comment: I use namespace to unbind this event later like this: `$(window).bind('mousewheel.content', function (e) {})`. so `var mousewheelevt = "onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : document.onmousewheel !== undefined ? "mousewheel" : "DOMMouseScroll"; mousewheelevt = mousewheelevt + '.content'` will work right?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    var isHover = $('.mainContent').is(':hover');

    if (!isHover) {
        $('.sidebar').scrollTop($('.sidebar').scrollTop() - event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/qPjs8/

Comment: well, that exactly it, but this solution has something because of what I got rid of body overflow in the first place.

You see, when I scroll element and this element stopped scrolling, I don't want other element to scroll. Also this has some strange behaviour when I just strated scrolling (other div scrolls too)

Comment: @A.Wolff is this cross browser solution? Can you submit this as answer?

Comment: @Mpa4Hu Should be cross browser (except IE8 but that's coming from mousewheel event, not related to code logic inside handler) and if it fits your needs, you should accept this answer instead because my jsfiddle was just an adaptation of this answer. EDIT: but then ya maybe this answer should be edited to fit your needs then

Comment: Well this kind of solves my question except There are times when `.scrollable will not be scrollable` and in that case I want to scroll .mainContent >.< sorry for so much trouble. I really had to write my question properly

Comment: @BradleyTrager what about if none is scrolled, I mean what if I rotated my mouse wheel outside of `.mainContent` and `.sidebar`. I still want `.mainContent` to scroll

Comment: Yes, for that you will have to check if the mouse is positioned over mainContent.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answering.
Unfortunately your answers was not enough for me because they solve problem for only one scrollable area. but `.sidebar` is not only scrollable and there can be modals and such things. We could remake that with class `.scrollable` as @A.Wolf suggested but I still think I came with better solution in my case.

Again thanks everyone for answering, this helped me to think what I really need and what my problem really is.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    if($(event.target).is('body')) {
        $('.mainContent').scrollTop($('.mainContent').scrollTop() - event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY);
    }
});
```

this is basic function, of course if somebody decides to use this, you need to make this cross-browser. as @Zword suggested

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
$(window).bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){
```

but before I wright this, I want to research a little more since Firefox suggests `DOMMouseScroll` [is not stable too.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll) [Wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel) event can be used instead.